# Calculate price of multiple drop downs to create price

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I have the code for a form with some drop down menus with different options in it. My question is how to assign each answer in the dropdown a different price and then calculate the sum of all the drop downs that are selected in an overall price box at the bottom of the form. I gather that I will need to use Javascript but I'm very new to this and do not fully understand it.

```
<form action="testemail@gmail.com" method="post"><fieldset>
    <select name="Colour">
            <option value="Choose a colour">Choose a colour</option>
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
            <option value="Purple">Purple</option>
    </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <select name="Size">
            <option value="Choose a size">Choose a size</option>
            <option value="Large">Large</option>
            <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="Small">Small</option>
            <option value="X Small">X Small</option>
    </select>
    </fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <select name="Material">
            <option value="Choose a material">Choose a material</option>
            <option value="Cotton">Cotton</option>
            <option value="Polyester">Polyester</option>
            <option value="Wool">Wool</option>
            <option value="Velvet">Velvet</option>
    </select>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit now" />
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you write any code. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: I did write it myself but i really do not have any kind of expertise in this area, but fair enough if you do not want to help, I realise I'm asking quite a lot.

Comment: It is not that I do not want to help but rather I want to encourage you to follow the guidelines for asking a question on SO. Please have a read through this faq http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to put somewhere actual prices or to get them. So one posibility is that you have some js object with prices or you can add prices to options like

```
<select name="Material">
        <option data-price='0' value="Choose a material">Choose a material</option>
        <option data-price='2'  value="Cotton">Cotton</option>
        <option data-price='2.5'  value="Polyester">Polyester</option>
        <option data-price='7'  value="Wool">Wool</option>
        <option data-price='13'  value="Velvet">Velvet</option>
</select>
```

and then you can sum all the prices from selected options like

```
var sum = 0;
var selected = $('option').prop('selected');
for(var i=0;i<selected.length;i++)
{
  if(selected[i].attr('data-price') !== '0' )
  {
  sum+= parseInt(selected[i].attr('data-price'));
  }
}
```

of course you need to make from that code function and bind it to selects change event

Comment: my answer uses jquery library

Comment: a fiddle would be more batter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vanilla Javascript approach:

```js
function getPrice(type) {
  var obj = document.getElementById(type);
  var price = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-price");
  if (price == null)
    price = 0;
  return parseInt(price);
}

function updatePrice() {
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "Total: $" +
    (getPrice("color") + getPrice("size") + getPrice("material"));
}
```

```html
<form action="testemail@gmail.com" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <select name="Colour" id="color" onChange="updatePrice()">
      <option value="Choose a colour">Choose a colour</option>
      <option value="Red" data-price="10">Red</option>
      <option value="Blue" data-price="20">Blue</option>
      <option value="Green" data-price="30">Green</option>
      <option value="Purple" data-price="40">Purple</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <select name="Size" id="size" onChange="updatePrice()">
      <option value="Choose a size">Choose a size</option>
      <option value="Large" data-price="40">Large</option>
      <option value="Medium" data-price="30">Medium</option>
      <option value="Small" data-price="20">Small</option>
      <option value="X Small" data-price="10">X Small</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <select name="Material" id="material" onChange="updatePrice()">
      <option value="Choose a material">Choose a material</option>
      <option value="Cotton" data-price="10">Cotton</option>
      <option value="Polyester" data-price="20">Polyester</option>
      <option value="Wool" data-price="30">Wool</option>
      <option value="Velvet" data-price="40">Velvet</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <div id="price">Total: $0
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit now" />
```